# Override classes with same package with Gradle in an Android project

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have to different source trees. In the second source tree couple of classes override tose in the first source tree. It looks like:

- project
  |

  - source-tree-1/src/com/companyname/MyClass.java

    - ...
  - source-tree-2/src/com/companyname/MyClass.java

    - ...

When compiling using Gradle I got the error 
Error:(20, 8) error: duplicate class: com.companyname.MyClass

Is there any way to specify to take the Class from source tree 2 and to ignore the other one?
Using exclude wont work because this will strip all classes specified by package and classname.

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += '../../sourcetree-1/'
    main.java.srcDirs += '../../sourcetree-2/'
    main {
        java {
            exclude 'com/companyname/MyClass.java'            
        }
   }
}
```

I need to override them using gradle because first the class from source tree 1 uses classes from the java.awt package which I cannot use in an Android project. The second class in source tree 2 will override the first one and not using any classes from forbidden packages.

Unfortunately I cannot alter the class in source tree 1 or any of the other classes using this class. So I need to override this class.

Answer (score 0):

I already defined two different source sets.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        seccomdev {
            java {
                srcDirs '../../SecCommerce-Dev/'
        exclude '....'
        exclude '....'
        exclude '....'
            }
        }

        main {
            java {
                srcDirs '../../SecCommerce-Android/src/'
                srcDirs '../../SecCommerce-Android/gen/'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the problem is how to combine those source sets while compiling the project.
If you google you will find something like:

```
main {
        java {
           compileClasspath += seccomdev.output
           runtimeClasspath += seccomdev.output
        }
    }
```

In this case I get the error: **Error:(122, 0) Could not get unknown property 'compileClasspath' for ...**

Another found solution is to add a dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile android.sourceSets.seccomdev
}
```

but than I get the error: **Error:(134, 0) Cannot convert the provided notation to an object of type Dependency: source set seccomdev.**

Using something like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile files(android.sourceSets.seccomdev.java)
}
```

I get: **Error:Cannot convert the provided notation to a File or URI: [src/seccomdev/java, ../../SecCommerce-Dev/].**

And using

```
dependencies {
    seccomdevCompile ':...'
}
```

will at least compile the gradle file and the whole compiling process starts. Unfortunately the java files from the first source tree/sourceSet are not compiled at all. SO I get hundreds of errors because imports in java classes of the second source set cannot be found.

---

So the question still is how to combine two different source trees in one compile because of code dependencies?